# Test if function "raises faster then linear"

Tags: hypothesis-testing

We are given a noisy sample from a function $f(x)$, that can be approximated as some kind of a power function $f(x) \approx \mathcal{O}(x^p) + \varepsilon$, assuming $\varepsilon$ being homoscedastic, Gaussian noise. We want to test $H_0$: the increase of $f(x)$ is not faster then linear with $x$ ($p \le 1$), vs $H_1$: the increase of $f(x)$ is faster then linear ($p > 1$). What is the best way to conduct such test?

Comment: I guess x is strictly positive, is it?

Comment: The "best way" is determined by additional information which includes (at a minimum) (1) the nature of the noise and (2) your loss function. Could you fill us in about those?

Comment: @carlo yes, corrects

Comment: @whuber additive Gaussian noise and squared error.

Comment: Are your $x$ large enough so that the $x^p$ term dominates, or might there be other behavior which would make the assumption $f(x) \approx Cx^p$ invalid?

Comment: @DemetriPananos it can be assumed that we have samples over whole range of possible values of $x$, so that’s not the case.

Comment: Tim, that's only half a reply.  It's good to know you're confident some data are in the asymptotic regime--but what can you tell us about the presence of smaller $x$ values where $f$ might not yet have attained its asymptotic behavior? As an example to illustrate some of these concerns, suppose $f(x)=10/(1+x^2)+x^{3/2}$ for $x\ge 0$ and you have samples at $x=0.01,0.02,0.03,\ldots,3$ with standard normal error. The smaller values of $x$ are a problem; and, although arguably an asymptotic regime has been reached for the larger values, it will be hard to determine that $p\gt 1.$

Comment: @whuber I'm afraid it is not possible for me to add much more details, since this would be used also for the future data, unknown to me. I expect to see many such samples and need to tag them as rising higher then linear based on the data. It can be assumed that those could be fairy well approximated with simple power functions $a + bx^p$, but corrupted with noise to different degree. I am aware of many possible issues with testing this, hence the question.

Answer (score 3):

Saying that a function “raises faster then linear” essencialy means that its derivative increases, meaning, its second derivative is positive.

The way you approximate the second derivative of a function is with a parabola. This is true for Taylor decomposition, when you want to approximate a function starting from a point evaluation of the function and its derivatives, but it works also for least squares. When fitting a straight line to your data, you are imposing a model with constant first derivative, but this can be amended adding a quadratic term, then the second derivative is constant, and you can allow it to vary adding a cubic term now, and so on.

But don't worry about how that (second) derivative varies, just settle with a mean estimate, it's the best thing you can use for testing.

When you consider a null model, that's the average $y$ value. When you have a linear model, the slope measures the average increment, when you include a quadratic term, that's the average second derivative. Simply test that for being positive.

Comment: A concern with this type of approach is that “growing super-linearly” is an asymptotic statement, and you can violate this second derivative statement locally without issue. What you have essentially proposed is to test for being strictly convex using polynomials, which is not quite the same as growing super-linearly (aside from other issues using polynomials, one can also estimate the function by ML under a convexity assumption).

Comment: you can estimate it as you want, but how will you make a valid statistical test on "growing super-linearly"? all you have is local data. not asymptotes, noisy data. Either the sample Tim collected is a fair representation of reasonable use cases of $x$ (in that case the claim that $f(x)$ raises more than linearly is indeed local), or the only thing he can do is extrapolating the asymptotic behaviour of $f$.

Comment: That is what makes the question interesting. My point is that fitting a polynomial is not a robust solution, nor is testing for convexity. Testing for convexity itself can be done in a more robust way than fitting a polynomial, but that still isn’t quite what we want. The question should be what *additional* assumptions need to be made for a robust solution to be possible, because the question as stated in OP is probably ill-posed.

Comment: I also can’t make sense of super-linear growth as a local statement because any continuous function on a bounded closed interval would be sub-linear trivially.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you already know that $f$ is increasing, we can further posit that it increases super-linearly if its first derivative is monotone increasing in $x$ (this also makes it a convex function). Since we’re working with a discrete, countable set of observations

$$\{ (x_1, f_1) , (x_2, f_2), \dots, (x_n, f_n) \}$$

we can’t observe derivatives. But we can take a look at some form of discrete derivative, such as the forward difference of the series

$$\Delta f_i = f_{i+1} - f_i$$

for $i \in \{1, \dots, n-1\}$ (in this case, you'll have to discard the last observation $x_n$). Fitting a polynomial or a particular function by regressing $\Delta f_i$ on $x_i$ and checking the significance of the coefficients is not a robust solution since the functional form of the derivative can really take any non-polynomial shape. Also p-values of the regression coefficients aren’t accurate if there are significant departures from normality.

This is why I would instead recommend checking something like rank correlation between $\Delta f$ on $x$. Namely, [Spearman correlation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spearman%27s_rank_correlation_coefficient) $\rho$ is a  non-parametric correlation based on rank which assess the monotonicity between two variables. And its statistical distribution is known both in small samples and large samples.

Thus, the one-sided test

$$H_0: \rho( \Delta f , x) = 0$$
$$H_A: \rho( \Delta f , x) > 0$$

if rejected, would lend credence to the claim that $f$ is indeed super-linear in $x$.

**Numerical Example.** Here, I'll generate two functions $f_0$ and $f_1$ with a $p$ of .8 and 1.2, respectively. Then I'll show that spearman correlation can distinguish which one is super-linear.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import spearmanr as sp # this is spearman correlation

delta = lambda series: series[1:] - series[:-1] # forward diff operator

n = 100 # size of sample
x = np.linspace(0,100,n) # x series
e = np.random.normal(0,1,n) # noise term
f0 = x**.8 + e # sub-linear function of x
f1 = x**1.2 + e # super-linear function of x
```

[image: Plot of functions f0 and f1]

```
sp(delta(f0),x[:-1])

correlation=-0.034, pvalue=0.735


sp(delta(f1),x[:-1])

correlation=0.309, pvalue=0.002
```

While it doesn't invalidate the results of this experiment, keep in mind that to get accurate Type 1 error rate, that this p-value (from scipy) is for a 2-sided test. In your case, you are looking for a 1-sided test.

Comment: OK, but the function is *noisy*, so while the overall trend would be increasing, it may have a lot of local "bumps", so some kind of smoothing would be needed, isn't it? That makes the procedure more complicated, because it depends on the smoothing algorithm.

Comment: This is a statistical hypothesis test for a reason: it’s designed to give you answers in spite of the noise in the data. So don’t worry about the bumps, you don’t need additional smoothing. If the super-linearity of $f$ is statistically significant, you should reject $H_0$ about $(1-\alpha)%$ of the time, where $\alpha$ is your test’s Type 1 error rate.

Comment: If $f$ wasn’t noisy, then you could simply check the deterministic condition $\Delta f_{i+1} > \Delta f_i$ for all $i$ (which doesn’t involve a hypothesis test).

Comment: I've just run run it on $y = x^p + \varepsilon$ and it returns significant Spearman $\rho$ for both $p=1$ and $p=2$, so doesn't seem to work on simple example. Could you clarify? Maybe give example?

Comment: Oh looks like there was a slight error in my notation. I'll correct this now and provide a numerical example in my answer for you.

Comment: Thanks for edit, this seems to work if the noise level is small, but if noise is something like $\mathcal{N}(0, 10)$ it starts to break.

Comment: It depends on the sample size and how extreme the super-linearity is. A p of 1.2 is only slightly super-linear which is why increasing noise can lead to a drop in significance. Furthermore, non-parametric tests tend not to be the most statistically efficient tests (meaning it takes more data to get an answer).

Comment: Sure, already +1'd it since it's an interesting solution.